# Do I need a Google Map API key for using GoogleMap in my project?

Tags: openlayers-2

Do I need a Google Map API key for using GoogleMap in my project where I am using OpenLAyers2.13?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you will find that Google Maps works without a key, Every official Documentation and sample I can currently access, says that you need to use a Key.

The [Getting Started page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) says:

> All Maps API applications* should load the Maps API using an API key.
>   Using an API key enables you to monitor your application's Maps API
>   usage, and ensures that Google can contact you about your application
>   if necessary. If your application's Maps API usage exceeds the Usage
>   Limits, you must load the Maps API using an API key in order to
>   purchase additional quota.

The OpenLayers Library works by calling the Google Maps API v3 in the background.

When Google Maps API v3 [was first released](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.in/2010/03/introducing-new-google-geocoding-web.html), it did not require a key. You should note that at that time, usage of Google Maps API was completely free of cost. Since then, high usage has become chargeable, and hence Google has started recommending that you use a key.

So you will find old tutorials, forum posts and answers which say that a key is not required, but I always use a key, as it just takes a minute or so to get the key, and there are no other downsides.

I'll strongly recommend that you use the Google Maps Layer with a Key.